# Why is the top panel of my garage door misaligned with the one below?

Tags: garage-door

A few days ago, I looked at my closed garage door, and noticed this. The top panel is bulging out slightly, leaving a small gap of about a quarter inch. It's flush on either side, or at least pretty close. I can only assume that their means there is an issue here, but I'm not certain how to fix it. I have inspected the inside of the garage door, and looked at the rails, but nothing seems visibly off. Before I call in a mechanic, is there anything I can do to fix this?

[image: Image showing offset garage door panel]

Comment: It's really hard to get context from that very close up picture. Unless your garage is heated/cooled and this is going to significantly impact your bill, you could just leave it. We've got dents and creases in a couple of our garage door panels. Have had for a few years. A friend who does garage door work took a look, put one of those folded panel stiffeners on one panel and pronounced it good to go. That was about 4 years ago.

Comment: I can't identify anything in that photo I'd describe as a "bulge". Please take another photo from another angle so that everything isn't completely flat to the eye and/or describe the situation with more detail.

Comment: @isherwood: I just tried to get better pictures, but it's not a terribly large amount, with the garage door flush on the sides, and protruding about a quarter inch in the middle in a gradual bow. If pushed, it goes back in a little, but pushes back out. The other panels are flush.

Answer (score 2):

Without a better view I can only offer general advice.

- Look for loose hinge screws. If you find any, snug them up. If they're stripped, reposition them or use larger screws.
- Look for damage or delamination in the panel. If the hinge screws are secure, is the panel skin detaching?
- Check for undue force from the opener. Is it pushing harder than it should when closed and at rest? If so, adjust opener travel as needed.
- Has there been damage from an impact? Look for dents and bends in the panel, the hinges, and the track.